# Cannot import flask_wtf into Python 3.9 venv

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code, flask-wtforms

No matter what I do, I cannot import flask_wtf, or any variation of it - flask-wtf, flask_WTF, flask-WTF, etc.  My linter doesn't recognize it (pylance in VSCode) - gives me error:

```
Import "flask_wtf" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports
```

When I try to run the code, I get:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\btaylor\repots\brannen\digitalocean\flask_app\forms.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask_wtf import Flaskform
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_wtf'
```

OS is Windows 10.  VSCode 1.66.1

Code:

```
from flask_wtf import Flaskform
from wtforms import (StringField, TextAreaField, IntegerField, BooleanField,
                     RadioField)
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired, Length

class CourseForm(FlaskForm):
    title = StringField('Title', validators=[InputRequired(),
                                             Length(min=10, max=100)])
    description = TextAreaField('Course Description',
                                validators=[InputRequired(),
                                            Length(max=200)])
    price = IntegerField('Price', validators=[InputRequired()])
    level = RadioField('Level',
                       choices=['Beginner', 'Intermediate', 'Advanced'],
                       validators=[InputRequired()])
    available = BooleanField('Available', default='checked')
```

I built a fresh directory, pip uninstalled Flask, created venv dir, activated, pip install the specific versions on this site: [digital ocean - How To Use and Validate Web Forms with Flask-WTF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpsoe.png): https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-and-validate-web-forms-with-flask-wtf and copied their code into the .py file.

My steps to install the libraries.

- .\venv\Scripts\activate
- pip install flask==2.0.2
- pip install Flask-WTF==1.0.0
- pip list

  Package      Version

  ---

  click        8.1.2
  colorama     0.4.4
  Flask        2.0.2
  Flask-WTF    1.0.0
  itsdangerous 2.1.2
  Jinja2       3.1.1
  MarkupSafe   2.1.1
  pip          22.0.4
  setuptools   58.1.0
  Werkzeug     2.1.1
  WTForms      3.0.1

pip freeze shows:

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\btaylor\repots\brannen\digitalocean> pip freeze
click==8.1.2
colorama==0.4.4
Flask==2.0.2
Flask-WTF==1.0.0
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.1
MarkupSafe==2.1.1
Werkzeug==2.1.1
WTForms==3.0.1
```

Snip of folder structure

[image: Snip of folder structure]

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  VSCode is running the Global Python.  However, if I enter into the cli IDE in the folder, it runs the local installation of Python in the virtual environment.

I found the python executable in the venv\Scripts folder.  In VSCode, entering (Windows) control-alt-P , select Python Interpreter, select my workspace that I'm in, "select at the workspace level", and then enter the path to the ..venv\Scripts\Python.exe .

Once VSCode is set to run the Python.exe from inside the virtual environment, then Python sees the additional modules installed in the venv.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old thread, but I found it while searching for an answer to the same problem.  My issue was this.  I installed wtforms in my development environment.  But my python interpreter (which I can select in the bottom right corner of the screen {} Python 3.11.4('yourdevelopmentenvironment':conda) was the base conda environment.  After switching to my actual development environment everything was accessible through pylance.

Comment: Is this any different than what was discussed in the self-answer?